# Fixed table body on scroll is flickering, used a tutorial by w3schools.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a simple table and the `tbody:first-child` element should be fixed when the user scrolls over it. The problem here is somehow my version of it doesn't work the same as in the tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header).

Tried using `padding-top` and without but no result. After some testing, I've realized something is wrong not with the `tbody:first-child` element itself but with others. The table layout is a bit different when shown in the W3Schools.com tutorial. I'll include a demo below and a short video so you can understand what's going on.

The video link to YouTube: https://youtu.be/7jxyabrIAoU.

---

I've removed the red header shown in the video so there won't be so many details here.

jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1cLthwgm/.

```js
var sticky = $("tbody:first-child").offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', () => {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= sticky) {
    $('tbody:first-child').addClass("sticky");
  } else {
    $('tbody:first-child').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

#container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 3rem 5vw 0;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

header {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F44336;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* The sticky class is added to the header with JS when it reaches its scroll position */

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.4;
  background-color: #03a9f4;
  padding: 18px 0;
}

th,
td {
  width: 25%;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

td {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #808080;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding: 16px 0;
}

th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f8f6ff;
}

th:nth-child(3),
th:last-child {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*** Grouped ***/

th:nth-child(3).content:after,
th:last-child.content:after {
  content: " ▼";
}


/***/

#table-data-2 {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="table-wrapper">
    <table>
      <tbody class="">
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Camper Name</th>
          <th class="content" title="Turn the descending sorting on">Points in past 30 days</th>
          <th title="Turn the descending sorting on">All time points</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody id="table-data-1">
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>sjames1958gm1</td>
          <td>131</td>
          <td>8781</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>rahsheen1</td>
          <td>105</td>
          <td>1201</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Smootimus1</td>
          <td>81</td>
          <td>95</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>lydatech1</td>
          <td>72</td>
          <td>2497</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>khaduch1</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>3494</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>cmccormack1</td>
          <td>58</td>
          <td>1055</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>zcassini1</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>1719</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>bradtaniguchi1</td>
          <td>52</td>
          <td>135</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>alpox1</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>1455</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>chaturyamakkena1</td>
          <td>45</td>
          <td>45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>JulyNightJulyNight1</td>
          <td>44</td>
          <td>44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>mathewsdrucker1</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>45</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <a href="https://codepen.io/Kestis500">Created by LukasLSC</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**EDIT** Please check this link. Tried using position: sticky, no effect. Not an overflow problem - https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/qoPOaE?editors=0100. Thank you.

Comment: I've made an edit to this question, check it, please.